# Align children flex container bottom not working

Tags: css, flexbox

I have 3 elements (1 image, 2 texts) inside a flex container. I am not able to align them on the bottom line. I tried with `margin-bottom: 0` `margin-bottom: auto` and it is not working.

```css
.distance {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.icon {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.text1 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.text2 {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="distance">
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="https://r00t4bl3.com/uploads/pp-840x830-pad-1000x1000-f8f8f8-c3edd4cbfc0d7bc9d7b02b27c6f6bac5.jpg" class="icon">
    <div class="text1">
      Golang
    </div>
    <div class="text2">
      Made by Google
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you were close, you didn't try margin-top:auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for vertical align in a flex display use the property `align-items`. in your case add `align-items: flex-end` at `flex` class. [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a good reference for flexbox.

Comment: Thanks! I used that too but in the wrong class, now works!

Comment: you're welcome! That's normal, with practice you will spot this small details. :)